# Recursive IIFE(Immediatly invoked function) in php 7

Tags: php

is it possible to use recursion with immediatly invoked function with php 7?
For exemple if i want to code a recursive version of a fibonacci series?

Following exemple does not work, but i hope it will help you to get my idea.

```
echo (function fn($x) {
     if($x==1||$x==0?0){
        return $x;
     }else{
        return fn($x-1) + fn($x+1);
     }
})(4);
```

Comment: Cant you just use a regular function?

Comment: in php it would be `$fn()` for closures, to grab that before its defined, you cant `) use($fn)`, so would need use `global`, https://3v4l.org/qh2OA, though it starts to look like a reducer in the end so might as well use [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) or a use normal recursive function